# How to make ScrollView 30% of the Screen and 70% for ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

The image in `ScrollView` looks good in small screens but not in large screens.
I want to make it automatically fit the screen, 30% `ScrollView` and 70% `ImageView`.
Thank you so much for your help :)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IVdisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/a" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVimage1"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/a" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your parent layout to `LinearLayout`, it automatically align with respect to given `weight`s try this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:weightSum="100" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IVdisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/a" />


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="30" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVimage1"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/a" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks! @Klaus66 how can I make all my images inside the ScrollView will fit the ScrollView (30% of the screen) I'm sure my code is wrong (android:layout_width="85dp" android:layout_height="75dp")